# dictionary C# (необходима правка)

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка ?

Ошибка `"Не удаётся преобразовать тип int в Т"`

Сразу говорю, я тут совсем не шарю.

Повторял прям за оратором, но он использовал `Dictionary<string, object>`

Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы всё правильно работало ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace FirstPlugin3
{
    class MainClass
    {


        private static Dictionary<string, int> dict;

        private static void Dobavlenie (string name, int kolichestvo)
        {

            if (!dict.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                dict.Add(name, kolichestvo);
            }
            else
            {
                dict[name] = kolichestvo;
            }

        }



        private static T Poluchenie<T>(string name) {
            int kol;
            T retName;
            dict.TryGetValue(name, out kol);

            try
            {
                retName = (T)kol;
            }
            catch {
                retName = default(T);
            }
            return retName;
        }







        static void Main(string[] args) {

            dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            Add("Vasek", 12);

            Console.WriteLine(Poluchenie<int>("Vasek"));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Удалить всё лишнее надо: https://ideone.com/teeuZ8

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace FirstPlugin3
{
  class MainClass
  {
    private static Dictionary<string, int> dict;

    private static void Dobavlenie(string name, int kolichestvo)
    {
      dict[name] = kolichestvo;
    }

    private static int Poluchenie(string name)
    {
      int kol;
      dict.TryGetValue(name, out kol);
      return kol;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
      Dobavlenie("Vasek", 12);
      Console.WriteLine(Poluchenie("Vasek"));
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо ! Буду дальше штрудировать Dictionary

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как это всё должно работать, если вместо имени "Vasek" , там будет нестатичная переменная ?
string name = namenonstatic;

Comment: Зачем вообще `TryGetValue`? o_O

Comment: @Vipz, не понял вопрос. С любой строковой переменной будет нормально.

Comment: @Suvitruf я хотел получать ключ и значение, но пока до этого не дорос.

Comment: @Suvitruf, чтобы не падало, когда нет в словаре ключа. Будет нолик. В оригинальном коде было `default(T)`, так что всё верно.

Comment: @Qwertiy вопрос вы поняли и ответили, у меня не работало, потому что я не туда пихал, щас на своём месте и всё работает.

Comment: @Qwertiy это лучше, чем сначала проверить на наличие ключа?

Comment: @Suvitruf, да. Потому что он одновременно проверит и достанет если есть. А если проверять самому, то он будет там дважды лазить за значением. Специально же метод сделали, который bool возвращает (правда, в этом коде он не используется).